# How to change the android::CoordinatorLayout screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

Hi I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4, and I was following some tutorials on youtube. But I realized in the screen preview of the Design tab, I only see a gray screen with "android::CoordinatorLayout" in the middle. It looks like this.[image]

Because of this, I cannot work with textView properly since I can't see anything. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: you see that red info icon just right of the layout zoom control..post the error what that syaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like XML file has some syntax error,or project build problems

Press 'Text' button next to the 'Design' button to open XML editor and see if the XML editor gives you some Error Message.

If you can't solve the problems,please try Build -> Clean Project/Rebuild Project 
or post the XML file here.